# zsh, on linux: typing lp cds me to /var/spool/lpd. Why?

Tags: linux, zsh

I tried to find if `lp` is a command:

```
% type lp
lp not found
```

It's also not an alias.

I do use an `oh-my-zsh` config. I searched the directory for hints, also found nothing.

I wonder if anyone knows how to dig a little to see what mechanism is changing my directory, I would like to know why this thing that isn't a normal command is doing something to change the shell's working directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `oh-my-zsh`, typing the username of a user changes to that user's home directory. `/var/spool/lpd` is typically the home directory of the `lp` user.

This behaviour is the combined effect of [`zsh`'s `auto_cd` and `cdable_vars` settings](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Changing-Directories).

`oh-my-zsh` sets these in its `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/theme-and-appearance.zsh` if you want to disable them.